# Computer Graphics: Math to Code

Tags: math, graphics

First, lets start out with my math background. I've taken calculus I - IV and Differential Equations. I've taken a first semester computer graphics course where we implemented pretty much our own graphics pipeline including shading using Phong without any graphics API.

I'm taking a graduate level Advanced Computer Graphics course this semester and when reading the math involved it loses me. This class is basically an image synthesize class. We'll build a ray-tracer in our first project and build on it from there on.

When reading up on advanced computer graphics, I'll usually get a bunch of math. I understand computer graphics is math heavy but I'm having problems when trying to figure out exactly how I'm suppose to implement the math into code. I'm really going to need to get the hang of this in order to excel in CG.

For instance, this article from GPU Gems:
http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch01.html
 There's a bunch of math, but I have no clue where to start implementing the math if I want to.

So, is there something I'm missing? 
 Am I suppose to look at the math and be able to derive the code?
 Are there tutorials/books out there that could help me understand what I'm needing to do?

Comment: How much linear algebra have you taken? Most of computer graphics is applied linear algebra.

Comment: I've taken linear algebra as well. I forgot to mention that. I never have problems with the linear algebra it's the complex integrals and how to translate them to code.

Comment: I'm not seeing any complex integrals in that article. Which bit are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That article is using FFTs, or actually inverse FFTs to generate a moving height field. Read up on FFTs. To do a 2d one, you first do 1d FFT on the rows, then the columns. Once you have the height field, the partial derivatives are probably obtained by taking the difference of adjacent heights along the x or y axis depending which partial it is. At a glance I don't see integrals in there, but they do appear in some graphics papers and there are methods for evaluating them.

I can also recommend looking around the ompf forum over at:
http://ompf.org/forum/

Comment: After looking at it again, it doesn't have any integrals. I do still have problems with when trying to translate to code. I'll check out the website.

Answer (score 1):

Programming for the sort of math you see in the GPU gems article would generally fall under numerical analysis. The more applied side of numerical analysis would be treated in a course or book on numerical methods or scientific programming. I'd suggest starting from the wikipedia article on [numerical analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_analysis) and looking at some of the specific linked articles. Once you know the names of some relevant methods, sample code is easy to find.

A tip: a big part of implementing derivatives and integrals is really just learning how to handle limits (in the mathematical sense) in your programs. Often, that's not explicitly stated.

Answer (score 0):

One tip I can give beyond just "study more math and practice" is that some mathematical constructs generally have an analogous construct in code it just may not be obvious.

Integrals (and summations) are often realized as loops in code or as sums across frames (in graphics this is often the case).  Derivatives and partials are changes between values which typically manifest as deltas across frames or between discrete elements like pixels.

These rules don't hold 100% but if you can start viewing the scarier math elements in terms of what code they generate it will make it easier to absorb.  It's important to work from a solid foundation so make sure you have the fundamentals down and the rest comes with experience and practice.